Why does Virtuoso automatically stop running for a period of time after starting in CentOS
In the bin directory of Virtuoso, use the command
nohup ./virtuoso-t -fd +configfile /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini &
to start Virtuoso. After a period of time, Virtuoso will automatically shut down.
The information in the log file is,
09:49:50 INFO: OpenLink Virtuoso Universal Server
09:49:50 INFO: Version 07.20.3240-pthreads for Linux as of Sep  8 2024 (a1fd8195bf)
09:49:50 INFO: uses OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
09:49:50 INFO: uses parts of PCRE, Html Tidy
09:49:52 INFO: Database version 3126
09:49:52 INFO: SQL Optimizer enabled (max 1000 layouts)
09:49:53 INFO: Compiler unit is timed at 0.000096 msec
09:50:00 INFO: Roll forward started
09:50:00 INFO:     41 transactions, 3528 bytes replayed (100 %)
09:50:00 INFO: Roll forward complete
09:50:00 INFO: Checkpoint started
09:50:00 INFO: Checkpoint finished, log reused
09:50:00 INFO: HTTP/WebDAV server online at 8890
09:50:00 INFO: Server online at 1111 (pid 827486)
10:09:56 INFO: Server received signal 1
10:09:56 INFO: Initiating quick shutdown
10:09:56 INFO: Server shutdown complete

I want to know what caused the Virtuoso service to automatically stop
I hope the Virtuoso service can run continuously without shutting down

Virtuoso can run continuously for years, if its host environment does not shut down or reboot.
The Server received signal 1 message usually goes along with closure of a terminal session where you're running it in foreground (-f). I suggest you try running it in a screen session that will persist when you close your terminal session. For instance —

screen -S {some-screen-name}
virtuoso +configfile {path-to}/virtuoso.ini -fd
ctrl+a+d to exit screen

For further Virtuoso-specific support, I recommend posting to the OpenLink Community Forum or the Virtuoso Open Source project on GitHub. (ObDislaimer: OpenLink Software makes Virtuoso, and employs me.)
